# IPHONE api demo

Tags: iphone

Android has a API demonstation you can install directly onto a Android device and see how the widget, buttons and all the other toys work.  Its great to see whats available.  I need the same thing for IPHONE but i cant find it under a search engine query.  Can anyone point me to where it is?

BTW: I found the link to the android API demo on this site i cant find the link but the apk application was titled "API demos" for android and i think it was from the Android developer site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's plenty of sample code at http://developer.apple.com/, section “[Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code)”.
You may want to take a look at [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007710), this is what you're looking for.

There is no “God App” which includes everything though.